# how to display data stored in an array for android using C# and ListView

Tags: c#, android, arrays, xamarin.android

I currently have the following code written in **C#** using **Xamarin** for **Android**:

```
EditText nameText = FindViewById<EditText> (Resource.Id.editName);
        Button btnAddContact = FindViewById<Button> (Resource.Id.btnAddContact);

        ListView contactView = FindViewById<ListView> (Resource.Id.listView1);

        btnAddContact.Click += delegate {
            string[] contactArr = nameText.Text.Split('\n');
        };
```

**First off**.. will the data that is input into the EditText field actually be stored to the array contactArr when the btnAddContact is clicked? There were no build errors so i wasn't sure if it would work..

My **main question** is, that if the data has been stored into the array, how do i go about displaying the data in a list view? Code example would do me the world of good as i don't have a clue where to go with this.. thanks.

**EDIT With New Code Tried.**

```
EditText nameText = FindViewById<EditText> (Resource.Id.editName);
        Button btnAddContact = FindViewById<Button> (Resource.Id.btnAddContact);

        ListView contactView = FindViewById<ListView> (Resource.Id.listView1);


        btnAddContact.Click += delegate {
            string[] contactArr = nameText.Text.Split('\n');

            var myAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, Resource.Id.listView1, contactArr);
            contactView.Adapter = myAdapter;
        };
```

EDIT with Error List:

`You must supply a resource ID for a TextView
Shutting down VM
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView
    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:386)
    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:362)
    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2159)
    at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1246)
    at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1158)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4825)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1052)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:590)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4825)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4825)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4825)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4825)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2176)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1874)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1089)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1265)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:989)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4351)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout cannot be cast to    android.widget.TextView
    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:379)
    ... 45 more`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ListView` is a stupid control, it does not know what to do with data itself, so it needs help from an `Adapter` that takes care of how to format the data.

To simply display alphanumerical values from an `EditText` which has been split into an array, you can use a `ArrayAdapter` which is built into Android.

```
var myAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1, contactArr);
```

The `ListView` needs to know about this adapter so you also have to do:

```
contactView.Adapter = myAdapter;
```

All this is very basic stuff that you can find a lot of information on in the [Xamarin Developer Center](http://docs.xamarin.com/). Xamarin also has a very nice [GitHub repository](https://github.com/xamarin) with loads and loads of samples.

**EDIT:**

Add this to Resource folder and call it `TextViewItem.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:id="@+id/textItem" 
    android:textSize="44sp"       
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

And alter your ArrayAdapter to match this:

```
var myAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, Resource.Layout.TextViewItem, contactArr);
```

Comment: Thanks Cheesebaron.. I added the code but i'm not sure i've put it in the right place as i got a huge error while running the app in the emulator. Here's what i did with the code -

Comment: Please edit your question with what you have tried, code in comments is unreadable.

Comment: Edited my answer, try that.

Comment: YES! That worked brilliantly! Thank you so much :) I had to change the file to a .axml because it wasn't recognized as just a .xml - next step is to add another text field to store the data and display them together.. i.e contact name and their phone number. Thanks for your help Cheesebaron.

Comment: Cheesebaron - when i click add contact it get's displayed all well and good below the edit field.. but how would i go about programming it so that when i type another name and press add contact it starts to build a list of names.. instead of currently just changing the one that is being displayed.

Comment: For that you will need to modify the data instead of setting it each time and then call `NotifyDataSetChanged` on the `Adapter`. For displaying custom kind of things you need to implement your own `Adapter`. See: http://redth.info/2010/10/12/monodroid-custom-listadapter-for-your-listview/

Comment: How would i go about passing the array on to another activity? For example, data shown in a TextView on my main activity, pass it over to a ListView on another activity called 'CallLog'.. instead of how we have just done it.. so it's basically echoing the number it's trying to phone.

Comment: Entirely another question, please search for it as I know it has been answered before.